# String Permutation with a few conditions

Tags: java, permutation, conditional-statements

I need a Java algorithm for a String permutation with a few conditions:

1. Every letter just once per word
2. The word has to end with a certain String
3. Only words that have a certain length should be shown.
4. Every letter can be in lower and upper case.

For example:

```
String perm = "abcdefgh";
```

Word length should be 7 or 8 and it should always end with `"g"` or "gh".

Okay:

```
abcdefgh
ABCdefgh 
ABCDEFGH
acbdefgh 
abdcefg
abcdefg
```

Not okay:

```
abc
abcdeghf
```

Comment: The first two Okay words are 8 letters long and the last two okay words don't end with "gh"

Comment: Do you want an algorithm, or Java code?  Algorithms, typically, are more high-level than a specific language implementation.

Comment: Now the first four examples have 8 letters.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I changed the description... it's been a really long day -.-


It doesn't matter if it's a algorithm or Java code.

Comment: I think it'd be a good idea to change the tag set to "homework" because 1) this smells like a homework problem. 2) There is nothing in the question that makes me think this is java-specific.

Comment: 3) There doesn't appear to be a good reason to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be a badge called "hall monitor" for telling students to do their own homework. :)

Comment: I agree with this, but I will say that it is kinda fun.:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

1. Create an array of available characters from the perm string.
2. Create the suffix string.  E.g. 'g' or 'gh'.
3. Remove from the character array each of the letters of the suffix.
4. Destination string = ""
5. For i=0 to MAX_LENGTH:
   {

   Add a random letter from the array to the destination string

   Remove that letter from the array

   }
6. Add the suffix to the destination string.

Run this multiple times to get more permutations.